# How to make jquery placeholders float with dynamically generated text fields

Tags: jquery, dynamic, css-float, placeholder

> I have 2 jquery scripts which I would like for them to work together. The first generates dynamic text >fields and works fine. The second script generates placeholders that float above a textfield. I'm trying >to obtain the same effect and placeholder formatting (the smaller blue color text floated above the text >field) once you click on the "Add Member" link on my dynamically generated text fields, as seen on the >static portion of the form. I tried binding the placeholder script with an on onclick function, but I >must be doing something wrong because; the placeholders float on the dynamically generated text fields >but it places the placeholder/label below the text field instead of above the text field, and it does >not apply the formatting to the floated text. I greatly appreciate your help on this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Team Members</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $('.my-form .add-box').click(function(){
                    var n = $('.text-box').length + 1;
                    if( 5 < n ) {
                        alert('Sorry, you have reached the maximum of members for this team!');
                        return false;
                    }
                    var box_html = $('<fieldset class="text-box"><legend for="box' + n + '">Member <span class="box-number">' + n + '</span></legend> <input type="text" name="name[]" value="" id="name' + n + '" placeholder="Name"/> <input type="text" name="surname[]" value="" id="surname' + n + '" placeholder="Surname"/><a href="#" class="remove-box">Remove</a></fieldset>');
                    box_html.hide();
                    $('.my-form fieldset.text-box:last').after(box_html);
                    box_html.fadeIn('slow');
                    return false;
                });
                $('.my-form').on('click', '.remove-box', function(){
                    $(this).parent().css( 'background-color', '#FF6C6C' );
                    $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                        $('.box-number').each(function(index){
                            $(this).text( index + 1 );
                        });
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
            
            
            //FLOATING LABEL SCRIPT///
             
              
              $(document).ready(function(){
              //$(".my-form .add-box").bind("click", function(){
            
              $(".my-form input:not([type=checkbox]):not([type=radio]):not([type=submit]):not([type=button]), .my-form select, .my-form textarea").each(function(e) {  
              
              $(this).wrap('<article></article>');
              var tag = $(this).attr("placeholder");
              //var tag= $(this).data("tag");
              $(this).attr("placeholder", "");
              $(this).after('<label for="name">' + tag + '</label>');
            });
            
            //});
            
            
            $('.my-form input:not([type=checkbox]):not([type=radio]):not([type=submit]):not([type=button]), .my-form select, .my-form textarea').on('blur', function() {
              if (!$(this).val() == "") {
                $(this).next().addClass('stay');
              } else {
                $(this).next().removeClass('stay');
              }
            });
            });
            
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            <!--
                #main {
                    max-width: 800px;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                }
                -->
            * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            outline:0;
            font-family:century gothic;
            font-size:1.0em;
            }
            body {
            background: #eee;
            }
            form {
            background: #fff;
            padding: 2em;
            width: 30em;
            margin: 5em auto;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
            }
            .my-form article {
            border: none;
            position: relative;
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            }
            .my-form input:not([type=checkbox]):not([type=radio]):not([type=submit]):not([type=button]), .my-form select, .my-form textarea {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 1em 0.25em 0.15em 0.25em;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            font-weight:bold;
            color:black;
            border: 0px solid #aaa;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
            /*box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);*/
            border-radius: 2px;
            }
            .my-form input:focus, .my-form select:focus, .my-form textarea:focus {
            outline: none;
            background: transparent;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #0099ff;
            }
            .my-form input + label, .my-form select + label, .my-form textarea + label {
            display: block;
            cursor: text;
            color: #777;
            transition: .15s ease-out all;
            position: absolute;
            top: 1.2em;
            left: 0.50em;
            }
            .my-form input:focus + label,
            .my-form label.stay {
            top: 0.35em;
            left: 0.50em;
            font-size: .7em;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #139dd7;
            transition: .15s ease-out all;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <h1 style="font-size: 200%; color:#0099ff;">2020 Fall Bible School - Registration</h1>
            <h2>Team Generator Form</h2>
            <div class="my-form">
                <form role="form" method="post">
                    <fieldset class="text-box">
                        <legend for="box1">Member <span class="box-number">1</span> (Team Coach)</legend>
                        <input type="text" name="name[]" value="" id="name1" placeholder="Name"/>
                        <input type="text" name="surname[]" value="" id="surname1" placeholder="Surname"/>
                    </fieldset>
                    <p><a class="add-box" href="#">Add Member</a> | <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The way your question is formatted makes it a bit confusing. It would also be helpful if you created and shared a codepen with the code formatted a bit better. https://codepen.io/pen/ I will say, you don't need to have 2 different $(document).ready calls and don't forget, every time you add a new element to a page, that new element will not be affected by any previously run javascript, so you'll need to run the little placeholder animation script again for each new  member that you add.

Comment: Thank you Brian, I appreciate your insight, and I will work on better formatting the code and create a Pen to share it as well.